# How to change value of a shared variable in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

I define the following class:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.X = theano.tensor.dmatrix('x')
        self.W = theano.shared(value=numpy.zeros((5, 2), dtype=theano.config.floatX), name='W', borrow=True)
        self.out = theano.dot(self.X, self.W)

    def eval(self, X):
        _eval = theano.function([self.X], self.out)
        return _eval(X)
```

After that I try to change the value of the `W` matrix and calculate with the new value. I do it in the following way:

```
m = test()
W = np.transpose(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]))
dn.W = theano.shared(value=W, name='W', borrow=True)
dn.eval(X)
```

The results that I get corresponds to the value of `W` that has been set in the `__init__` (all elements are zeros).

Why the class does not see the new value of `W` that I set explicitly after the initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created a new shared variable to python variable `dn.W`, however the theano's internal compute graph is still linked to the old shared variable.

To change value stored in existing shared variable:

```
W = np.transpose(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]))
dn.W.set_value(W))
```

**NOTE** If you want to use results from a function call to update shared variable, the better way is to use `updates` argument of `theano.function`. This eliminates unnecessary memory transfer if shared variable is stored in GPU.